# Poincare-Wirtinger inequality for $H^{1}(D)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

I have a question about Poincare-Wirtinger inequality for $H^{1}(D)$.

Let $D$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. We define $H^{1}(D)$ by
\begin{equation*}
H^{1}(D)=\{f \in L^{2}(D,m): \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \in L^{2}(D,m),\ 1\le i \le d\},
\end{equation*}
where $\partial f/\partial x_i$ is the distributional derivative of $f$ and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $D$. $H^{1}(D)$ becomes a Hilbert space with the usual Sobolev norm $\|\cdot\|_{H^{1}(D)}$.

In the following, we write $\nabla f$ for $(\partial f/\partial x_1,\ldots \partial f/\partial x_d)$. We also write $\|f\|$ for $(\int_{D}f^2\,dx)^{1/2}$

> **[Theorem 1]** Let $D$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with finite volume. We assume the canonical embedding $H^{1}(D) \subset L^{2}(D,m)$ is compact. Then, there exists a positive constant $C>0$ such that for any $f \in H^{1}(D)$
>   \begin{equation*}
> \|f-f_{D}\|\le C \|\nabla f\|,
> \end{equation*}
>   where $f_{D}:=m(D)^{-1}\int_{D}f\,dm$

[Proof of Theorem 1]

Define $X \subset H^{1}(D)$ by $\{f \in H^{1}(D) : f_{D}=0 \}$. Then, $X$ is a closed subspace of $H^{1}(D)$. It suffices to prove there exists a $C>0$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
(*)\quad \|f\|\le C \|\nabla f\| \ \text{ for any }f \in X
\end{equation*}
We prove $(*)$ by contradiction. We assume there exist a $\{f_n\} \subset X$ such that $\|f_n\|>n \|\nabla f_n\|$. We may assume $\|f_n\|_{H^{1}(D)}=1$.
As $f_n$ is a bounded sequence in $X$, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ and a $f \in X$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ weakly in $X$. $f_{n_k}$ is also denoted by $f_n$. By assumption, $f_n \to f$ in $L^{2}(D,m)$. Since 
$$1=\|f_n\|_{H^{1}(D)}\text{ and }\|f_n\|>n \|\nabla f_n\|$$
holds, $\|f_n\|\to \underline{1=\|f\|}$ and $\|\nabla f_n\| \to 0$. Since $f_n \to f$ in $L^{2}(D,dx)$ and $\|\nabla f_n\| \to 0$,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{D}(\nabla f_n,\nabla g)+\int_{D}f_n g\,dx\to \int_{D}fg\,dx.
\end{equation*}
for any $g \in X$. On the other hand, since $f_n$ convenes to $f$ weakly in $X$,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{D}(\nabla f_n,\nabla g)dx+\int_{D}f_n g\,dx\to \int_{D} (\nabla f,\nabla g)\,dx+\int_{D}fg\,dx.
\end{equation*}
Hence $\int_{D}(\nabla f,\nabla g)dx=0$ for any $g \in X$, which implies $\nabla f=0$ and $\Delta f=0$ in weak sense. By Wyle's Lemma $f$ is  smooth on $D$. Hence, $\nabla  f=0$ in classical sense. Since $D$ is connected, $f$ is a some constant. Since $ f \in X$, we have $f=0$, which contradicts to $\underline{1=\|f\|}$.

**My question and remark**

From the above proof, we do not know concrete estimates of C. If you know an another proof, please let me know.

Comment: You can easily check this yourself by looking into Evans PDE book (or probably any other).

Comment: It is correct. Just a remark, you don't need Wyle's lemma.  Indeed, you know that $\nabla f_n\rightarrow0$ and that $\nabla f_n\rightharpoonup\nabla f$ thus by uniqueness of weak limits in Hilbert spaces you get $\nabla f=0$

Comment: Umm... From your discussion how do you know that $f$ is a constant on $D$?

Comment: Weyl's Lemma rather – The constant $c$ is the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian in $D$, for the BVP $-\Delta u=\lambda u,  \int_D u=0.$

Comment: @sharpe ahhh ok, I see the problem. Well, it depends on what you know. To conclude I use the fact that $D$ is connected and the distributional gradient of $f$ is zero but also the use of Wyle's lemma is correct